# Why the code suppose to be a false but it turns out to be true

Tags: arrays, math

/*I tried to write a code to see if the sum of any  2 numbers in an array equals sum, but I cannot fix a bug that is if I input only one 4 it is still true*/

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector vec = new Vector();
        int sum = 8;
        int[] a = {1, 2, 4};
        int i;
        int k = a.length;

        for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
           vec.add(sum - a[i]);
        }
        for(int value : a) {
            if (vec.contains(value)) {
                System.out.println("true");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this might be a learning curve, try adding this print
`for(int value: a) {System.out.println("value:"+value+" , vector:"+vector); //Add after for...`
You should probably found the answer you seek and understand why value does not contain in variable "a". Hint: sum and sequence order.

Comment: I do not even know where to start. 1. Is a void function, so it does not return anything. 2. You have a hard coded print True line of code, so it will always print true.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. The last element in `vec` is 4 and the last element in `a` is also 4 so the last `for` loop in your code will always print **true** when checking whether the last element in `a` is contained in `vec`, since `vec` does contain a 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the debugger to see the values of the variables during the calculation to see if they are doing the expected operations.